# equation = 0, idk why this happens but it is not in integer data type

Tags: java, math

Here is a code operating a simple clock (second chance) Page Replacement, my problem is that my math equation (double pager = fault/ref_len*100;) always outputs to 0 when i call it in my output line.
i wish to make my variable output the correct product but it always == to 0 when i output it on my terminal.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class ClockReplacement {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int frames, pointer = 0, hit = 0, fault = 0,ref_len;
    int buffer[][];
    int reference[];
    int mem_layout[][];
    int used_layout[][];
    
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of Frames: ");
    frames = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    
    System.out.println("Please enter the length of the Reference string: ");
    ref_len = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    
    reference = new int[ref_len];
    mem_layout = new int[ref_len][frames];
    used_layout = new int[ref_len][frames];
    buffer = new int[frames][2];
    for(int j = 0; j < frames; j++)
    {
     buffer[j][0] = -1;
     buffer[j][1] = 0;
    }
    System.out.println("Please enter the reference string: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < ref_len; i++)
    {
        reference[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 0; i < ref_len; i++)
    {
     int search = -1;
     for(int j = 0; j < frames; j++)
     {
      if(buffer[j][0] == reference[i])
      {
       search = j;
       hit++;
       buffer[j][1] = 1;
       break;
      } 
     }
     if(search == -1)
     {
      
      while(buffer[pointer][1] == 1)
      {
       buffer[pointer][1] = 0;
       pointer++;
       if(pointer == frames)
        pointer = 0;
      }
      buffer[pointer][0] = reference[i];
      buffer[pointer][1] = 1;
      fault++;
      pointer++;
      if(pointer == frames)
       pointer = 0;
     }
        for(int j = 0; j < frames; j++)
 {
  mem_layout[i][j] = buffer[j][0];
  used_layout[i][j] = buffer[j][1];
 }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < frames; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < ref_len; j++)
            System.out.printf("%3d %d ",mem_layout[j][i],used_layout[j][i]);
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    
    System.out.println("#Page Faults: " + fault);
    double pager = fault/ref_len*100;
    System.out.println("%page replacement: " + pager);
    }

}
```

Comment: What are the values for `fault` and `ref_len`?

Comment: it's user defined i think because i input the length of reference and the fault is after the main process takes place

Comment: Knowing the actual values of fault and ref_len in some test case is crucial to understanding why the output of that test case is zero.

Comment: `fault` and `ref_len` are both integers, so `fault/ref_len` will give an integer result (0, 1, 2, ...). Since you assign the result of `fault/ref_len*100` to a double variable you seem to expect a fractional result. To get a double result you could rewrite the expression as `100.0*fault/ref_len`